# IntelliJ IDEA: maven reporting plugin issue

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Since intellij version 2020.1 I'm facing an issue where intellij is checking where reporting configuration is available in pom. This is causing errors for me constantly even though I have no reporting plugins in my pom in any of my projects. Here's an image of the validation in my maven sidebar. [image]

Comment: Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245137#focus=Comments-27-4255539.0-0 help? You may want to switch to the older Maven version instead of using the bundled Maven if you don't plan to fix this problem.

Comment: Awesome @CrazyCoder that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I switched back to 3.3.9 and that seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is reported by the new Maven versions, there was a [related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245137#focus=Comments-27-4255539.0-0).

You can either switch back to the older Maven version (such as 3.3.9) which will not report this error or fix the error in `pom.xml`.